# Will a x64 PHP/MYSQL build support full 64bit timestamps on a 64bit Windows Server

Tags: php, mysql, windows

Probably a silly question, but I need to find the answer.  An application we are writing needs to handle distant past and future dates, and I think handling our dates as 64bit Unix Timestamps would be an easy solution provided I understand the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) correctly, which states that the maximum int value is platform dependent and always signed.  Thus a x64 platform should support 2^63 bites while a x86 platform should support 2^31 max bites.

Basically, the application only deals with integer timestamps to make our fairly complicated algorithms a little 'bit' simpler.  However, trying to handle distant past or future timestamp values causes the expected overflow for any value greater than +/- 2^31 in PHP for our current x86 build.  My solution is to simply compile a x64 PHP build with the free visual c++ studio download, but before I dive into that I'd like to know if my assumption is correct - **"A Windows x64 PHP build will correctly handle 64bit int values, and correctly convert the Windows 'ticks' into a 64bit Unix Timestamp for its native date/time functions as it does for a x86 build."**

For example:

```
echo mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2055);
```

will return the correct timestamp, instead of **false**.

The same thing applies for MYSQL timestamps.  For example:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2065-11-30 10:30:19');
```

will return the correct value, instead of **'0'** as it does for the current x86 build we have running.

-I hope I'm not too ambiguous. Thanks in advance.  We're just a bunch of science geeks and not real programmers here, and are struggling with this 'trivial' issue.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question: I tried running some tests a while back, expecting a full 64-bit timestamp giving me date ranges between the big bang and the sun burning out, but found that it was still only the lower 32-bits that were being processed when passed to the date() function, even though echoing the timestamp integer value was showing the full 64-bit range.

**EDIT**

However, setting a dateTime object using the 64-bit range of values worked without problem.

Comment: Well that's sort of the same boat we're in.  A goofy web-app to remotely handle quick and dirty data generated from instruments that we'll dump into mysql.  I'm trying to track down the the actual timestamp functions in source and see what the deal is.  Near as I can the type is defined as long, which should address 64 bits if compiled with x64 instructions, I assume, yet everything found online seems contrary.  I'm worried there is some sort of 'error' correction for backwards compatibility.